# When I call an pre-existing event handler from a subroutine, it doesn't come back. VB

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

I'm looking to call a pre-existing event handler subroutine from the form_Load event handler.
But the below doesn't work because control doesn't come back and I want to do more.

**UPDATE:**
I'm new to this so I don't know what the proper protocol is but...
 The reason for the non-return was that a statement like the below ended the subroutines execution.

`If aLabel.Tag = 1...`

the fix was adding `New` to the declaration to create an instance of it, ie..
changing....
`Dim aLabel As Label`
 ... to ...
`Dim aLabel As New Label`

I'm surprised I didn't get a warning but instead they just abruptly stopped execution of the sub. That wasn't very helpful :)
Thanks again for your time guys...
(Maybe this question should be deleted now that it has served its purpose)
@konrad  @karl

**END OF UPDATE**

What doesn't work is....

```
Private Sub Form1_Load...

button1_Click(sender, e)    'But Control doesn't come back.

end sub
```

Do I change the `sender` to something?
Thanks in advance
 Dave

Comment: No, the control *does* come back. Something else is happening here.

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't come back`? A `Subroutine` does not return a value; however a `Function` does.

Comment: Author of Question:  
For those who are interested... The reason for the non return was that the statement below ended the subroutines execution.   
`If aLabel.Tag = 1... ` 
....the fix was changing....  
`Dim aLabel As Label `
... to ...   
`Dim aLabel As New Label `

... I'm surprised I didn't get a warning but instead they just stopped execution.  ... Thanks again for your time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking event handlers like this is a bad idea, because you are trying to simulate the event context by making `sender` and/or `EventArgs` be something else.

Instead, put the logic that you want to invoke into a `Subroutine` or `Function` and have your `Form1_Load` method call that; likewise if you really do have a real click event handler, then that handler code can call the method too, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load()
    DoSomeWork()
End Sub

Protected Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    DoSomeWork()
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomeWork()
    ' Put logic here that you want to do from form load and a button click
End Sub
```

This has the benefit of making the code cleaner, clearer and easier to maintain as you only need to change the logic in one place should you need to change the logic.

Note: Obviously, you can pass parameters to the `DoSomeWork` method, if need be, and change it to a `Function` if you need it to return something.

Comment: This is much cleaner than calling `button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)`, heh heh.

Comment: @helrich - I have worked with people that do exactly that, pass `Nothing` to event handlers, it is maddening.

Comment: Karl, by not come back I mean, the stuff after it in Form1_Load does not get executed. I double checked by tracing it in debug.  I like your solution, my goal was not to double up the same code. Your approach works for me. Thanks for you time.  Dave

Comment: For those who are interested... I experienced the same abrupt "Kicking out" of a different subroutine when I asked the question..  If activeDigitOrArrow.Tag = 1...   the fix was changing...  Dim activeDigitOrArrow As Label... to   Dim activeDigitOrArrow As New Label

Comment: Restart: 5 minute edit limit

For those who are interested... I experienced the same abrupt "Kicking out" of a different subroutine when I asked the question....  
If aLabel.Tag = 1 ... 
....the fix was changing....  
Dim aLabel As Label ...
... to ...   
Dim aLabel As New Label ...

... I'm surprised I didn't get a warning but instead they just stopped execution.  ... Thanks again for your time ...